# C#, .NET : hide DOS command-prompt window

Tags: c#, .net, command-line, forms

In C# and .NET, I wrote an application that runs in a `Form` (using `Windows.System.Forms`).  I use InnoSetup to install and I am able to start the application via Windows' Start button.

My problem:  a DOS command-prompt window appears along with the Form.  How can I prevent the DOS window from appearing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Did you create the application using Visual Studio? If so, in the project properties, in the Application tab, there's a setting called "Output type". If this is set to "Console Application", a command-prompt window will appear when running the program, as well as the form. Setting it to "Windows Application" (the default for Windows Forms projects) will sort this out.

EDIT: Just saw your comment on the other answer. This setting corresponds to the "/target" switch for the compiler. `/target:exe` will give you the command-prompt, `/target:winexe` will just show the form. Hopefully anyway! I'm just going by the build output from Visual Studio.

Comment: I compiled with "csc.exe /target:winexe", and that did the trick!  Thank you, Partario!

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like you compiled the application with the wrong target--likely, you need to tell Visual Studio to compile it targeting a GUI executable, not a CLI executable.

You can do this in the project preferences.

Comment: I don't have a project -- I'm compiling from the command-line.

Comment: Aha--then you need to compile with /target:winexe. :)